# Is there a way to bulk add URLs to a certain YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Say I have a list of URLs (videos), and I would like to add them to a certain playlist on my YouTube channel. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -2):

No you have to add one by one manually.